# What condition can I use to check if a button tab is in a range?

Tags: objective-c

I need to check if a button tab is between 91 and 96 inclusive.

I don't want to write:

```
if (button.tab==91) {
    ...
}
if (button.tab==92) {
    ...
}
...
```

Instead, I want to use a single condition.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
if (button.tab >= 91 && button.tab <= 96)
{
    // do stuff!
}
```